# How to create a Docker image with proprietary dependencies excluded

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, podman

I'm currently working on making a Docker image of our open-source program publicly available. However, one of the dependencies is proprietary, and we're restricted from including it in the Docker image. My goal is to provide a Docker image that excludes this dependency, allowing the end-user to share its installer with the container. Upon the container's initial launch, it should install the dependency automatically, streamlining the process for the end-user. As the installation process for the dependency is time-consuming, it should be only run once.

I've considered using a volume to share the installer, but I'm unsure if that is the most sophisticated solution, and before investing too much time, I want to seek advice on feasible approaches to tackle this problem efficiently.

Comment: Can you provide a Dockerfile that lets the end-user build their own image, including the proprietary dependency? Maybe base the Dockerfile on an image that you also provide.

Comment: "I've considered using a volume": you can't distribute a volume (they're not part of the image -- they're storage associated with the local container runtime).